# How to check if a date time is before midday

Tags: python, datetime

I have a datetime object in python and I would like create a function to check whether the input is in the morning or afternoon on the day of the datetime (ie, before or after 12pm). How to I manually create the time `12:00` and can I use greater than or lesser than symbols for this (`<`, `>`)?

Comment: you can make your decision based *only* on the hour part.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Call the [`datetime.datetime.time()` method](http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.time) on the `datetime` object and compare it with a `datetime.time()` object:

```
if dt.time() < datetime.time(12):
```

or just look at the [`datetime.datetime.hour` attribute](http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.hour):

```
if dt.hour < 12
```

The latter is simpler, the former gives you more flexibility to compare against times that include a minute component:

```
if dt.time() < datetime.time(12, 30)
```

Demo:

```
>>> import datetime
>>> dt = datetime.datetime.now()
>>> dt
datetime.datetime(2014, 2, 10, 10, 39, 30, 768979)
>>> dt.time() < datetime.time(12)
True
>>> dt.hour < 12
True
>>> dt = dt.replace(hour=20)
>>> dt
datetime.datetime(2014, 2, 10, 20, 39, 30, 768979)
>>> dt.time() < datetime.time(12)
False
>>> dt.hour < datetime.hour
False
```