# Comparing time in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7

My current project is scraping weather data from websites for calculation. Part of this calculation involves different logic depending on if the current time is before or after noon.

```
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import numpy as np  

# Arkansas State Plant Board Weather Web data
url1 = "http://170.94.200.136/weather/Inversion.aspx"
response1 = requests.get(url1)

soup1 = BeautifulSoup(response1.content)
table1 = soup1.find("table", id="MainContent_GridView1")

data1 = pd.read_html(str(table1),header=0)[0] 
data1.columns = ['Station', 'Low Temp (F)', 'Time of Low', 'Current Temp (F)', 'Current Time',  'Wind Speed (MPH)', 'Wind Dir', 'High Temp (F)', 'Time Of High']

print(url1)
print(data1[0:4])

array1 = np.array(data1[0:4])
```

This is my code to bring in the data I need. However, I don't know how to compare the current time I request as a Unicode string to see if it is before or after noon. Can anyone help me with this?

Edit: some data from the current request

```
    Station  Low Temp (F) Time of Low  Current Temp (F) Current Time  \
0  Arkansas          69.0     5:19 AM              88.7      2:09 PM   
1    Ashley          70.4     4:39 AM              91.2      2:14 PM   
2   Bradley          69.4     4:09 AM              90.6      2:14 PM   
3    Chicot         -40.2     2:14 PM             -40.2      2:14 PM   

   Wind Speed (MPH)  Wind Dir  High Temp (F) Time Of High  
0               4.3       213           88.9      2:04 PM  
1               4.1       172           91.2      2:14 PM  
2               6.0       203           90.6      2:09 PM  
3               2.2       201          -40.1     12:24 AM
```

Comment: What do you mean current time you request as unicode string? Can you assign it to a variable, then `print current_time` and tell us what it is?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to check if a date time is before midday](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21674782/how-to-check-if-a-date-time-is-before-midday)

Comment: @Bahrom One of the columns of the table I request is 'Current Time' and values in that table are unicode.

Comment: It's generally easier for us to help you if you give us some sample data. As it is, it appears that your times are in "H:MM PM" format, such as "2:09 PM"?

Comment: Take a look at [parsing time string in python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10494312/parsing-time-string-in-python)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just check if the meridian is PM or AM.

```
 time = "2:09 PM"
 meridian = time.split(' ')[-1] # get just the meridian
 before_noon = meridian == 'AM'
 after_noon = meridian == 'PM'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
t = pd.to_datetime(data1['Current Time'][0:1][0])
noon = pd.to_datetime("12:00 PM")
if t < noon:
    print("yes")
else:
    print("no")

>>> no
t
>>> Timestamp('2016-07-11 14:04:00')
noon
>>> Timestamp('2016-07-11 12:00:00')
```