# django template print either "good morning or afternoon" depending on time of day

Tags: python, django, html

Morning,

I'm trying to create a template for an email and I'm unsure on how to get the  greeting to flip between "Morning, afternoon and evening" depending on time of day that it is selected to be sent.

Any ideas

current template code

```
{% if hour < 12 %}
    morning
{% elif hour > 12 %}
   afternoon
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `now` in your template like this:

```
{% now "H" as current_time %}

{% if current_time > 12 %}
    afternoon
{% else %}
    morning
{% endif %}
```

Comment: That comparison won't work, because `current_time` is a string. An ugly little hack to convert it to integer: `{% if current_time|add:"0" > 12 %}`

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this:

```
{% if now < midday %}  
    morning
{% else %}
   afternoon
{% endif %}
```

Where midday is defined as:

```
midday= datetime.time(12)
```

Of course that that midday must be part of your template context!

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/templates/builtins/#now
[How to check if a date time is before midday](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21674782/how-to-check-if-a-date-time-is-before-midday)

Comment: thank you, to build on this if i wanted to include "evening" so then my email covers all points of the using "midday" as a baseline what is the best way to do this

Comment: I didn't get it! what do you want to do ? :)